# Javascript Code not working after pressing on back button on browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am working on project which using javascript to get data from database and show it in table.

Every column in the table has action column where user can (edit / delete ..etc)

When the user clicks the edit button he will be redirected to the edit page.

After he has finished the editing, he presses the backbutton on the top left of Chrome browser, to get back to the table page, but the problem is the data is not loading and the table is empty till I refresh the page, then the script code is working and data has been shown in the table.

I don't understand why is that happening, why the javascript code is not working after I click the back button

This is my code it is getting data from database and show it in the table
after calling `initTable2` function

```js
var handleISI = function() {
  getData();

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      type: "GET",
      url: "/admin/ISIM/GET_ISIMng",

      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = data;

        ISI.initTable2(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = [];

        ISI.initTable2(data);
      },
    });
  }
};



return {
  init: function() {
    // initISITable();
    handleISI();
    handleElements();
    //     handleAttributes();
    handleADDISI();
  },
  initTable2: function(data) {
    //child row delete
    ISITable.find("tbody")
      .find("tr.shown")
      .removeClass("shown")
      .next()
      .remove();
    //dd report check
    var isDD = false;
    var isDDReport = false;

    if (data != undefined) {
      ISITable.DataTable().destroy();
      ISITable.empty();
      ISITable.html("");

      if (data != "") {
        var thead, tbody;

        thead = "<thead><tr>";
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
          if (key == "id") {} else {
            thead += "<th>" + (jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang].name) + "</th>";
          }
        });
        (thead += "<th class='text-right'>" + (jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang].actions) + " </th>"),
        (thead += "</tr></thead>");
        ISITable.append(thead);
        tbody = "<tbody>";
        var seq_id = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (isDD) {
            tbody += "<tr><td class='details-control'></td>";
          } else {
            tbody += "<tr>";
          }
          var users_id;
          var name_val;

          $.each(data[i], function(key, value) {
            if (key == "id") {
              users_id = value;
            } else {
              if (key == "name") {
                name_val = value;
              }
              if (key == "username") {
                tbody +=
                  "<td>" +
                  '<i class="fa fa-user" style="color: #5d56f3;"></i>   ' +
                  value +
                  "</td>";
              } else if (key == "totalSession") {
                tbody +=
                  "<td>" + value.formatNumber() + "</td>";
              } else {
                console.log(value);


                tbody += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
              }
            }
          });

          tbody +=
            '<td class="text-right"><a href="javascript:;"  id="attributebutton"  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary   btn-sm mt-1  green   attribute  rounded" data-toggle="tooltip" title=' +
            jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang]
            .attribute +
            ' data-original-title="Attribute"    data-id= ' +
            users_id +
            "  data-name= " +
            encodeURIComponent(name_val) +
            '  "    ><i class="fa fa-list  " style="color:white" ></i></a>';
          tbody +=
            ' <a href="javascript:;"  id="editbutton"   class="btn btn-sm btn-success  btn-sm mt-1  attribute  rounded" data-action="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title=' +
            jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang].edit +
            ' data-original-title="Edit"  data-id= ' +
            users_id +
            " data-name= " +
            encodeURIComponent(name_val) +
            '    >  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt " style="color:white" ></i></a>';

          tbody +=
            ' <a href="javascript:;"   class="btn btn-sm btn-danger  btn-sm mt-1  delete_isi  rounded" data-action="Delete"  data-toggle="tooltip" title=' +
            jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang]
            .delete +
            ' data-original-title="Delete" data-id= ' +
            users_id +
            "   data-name= " +
            encodeURIComponent(name_val) +
            ' "    >  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt  " style="color:white" ></i></a>';
          tbody +=
            ' <a href="/admin/ISI/' +
            users_id +
            '"   class="btn btn-sm btn-sm mt-1  btn-warning  green    rounded"  data-action="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" title=' +
            jsTranslation[document.documentElement.lang]
            .manage +
            ' data-original-title="Manage"   data-id= ' +
            users_id +
            "   data-name= " +
            encodeURIComponent(name_val) +
            ' "    >  <i class="fa fa-globe  " style="color:white" ></i></a> ';

          tbody += "</td>";
          tbody += "</tr>";
          seq_id++;
        }
        tbody += "</tbody>";
        tbody += " ";
        ISITable.append(tbody);

      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    var table = ISITable;

    // var columnDefs = [{ className: "text-left", targets: "_all" }];

    if (data == undefined) {
      // columnDefs = [{ className: "dt-center", targets: "_all" }];
    }

    var oTable = table.DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      ordering: false,
      paging: true,
      lengthMenu: [
        [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
        [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"], // change per page values here
      ],
      pageLength: 10,
      dom: "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-9 col-sm-12 topLenght'l><'col-md-3 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

      // columnDefs: columnDefs,
      language: $.fn.dataTable.language,
      className: "dt-center",
      language: {
        url: window.location.origin + "/i18N/" + document.documentElement.lang + ".json",
      },
    });

    //Top lenght selector
    var x = 10;
    if (x == "") {
      x = "10";
    }
    var optionhtml = "";
    if (x == "10") {
      optionhtml += "<option selected value='10'>10</option>";
    } else {
      optionhtml += "<option value='10'>10</option>";
    }
    if (x == "20") {
      optionhtml += "<option selected value='20'>20</option>";
    } else {
      optionhtml += "<option value='20'>20</option>";
    }
    if (x == "30") {
      optionhtml += "<option selected value='30'>30</option>";
    } else {
      optionhtml += "<option value='30'>30</option>";
    }
    var xx = " ";

    //top kutusunu taşır.
    $("#reporttable_wrapper").find(".topLenght").append(xx);
  },
};
})();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ISI.init(); // init metronic core componets
});
```

Comment: Clicking the back button in browsers that cache the page is the problem unless the page . You should either redirect the browser to the page that you came from (not by navigating back) once the details have been saved. Or provide some other mechanism for the user to do it manually. Forget about using the browser back button

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a metronic table. I have worked on a metronic website, are you using the regular JS version? I can't tell which one you are using.

I have used the Angular version and have had this problem occur when there was an asynchronous process inside a synchronous function.

From looking at the code, I can't see what the functions, handleISI(), handleElements(), handleADDISI() do so I cannot comment on them. I tried searching a few snippets on the latest metronic version, and couldn't find them. If you are using a pre v7 version, please let me know.

After all that, looking at the code you have given me, there are only two things that stand out to me

1. The init function is synchronous and your ajax call is async. Meaning that your handlers get initiated before the data is retrieved. Which may or may not be the cause of your problem. You haven't shared the edit action either, I will have to assume that the edit action might not be adding the data locally and only on the server, which means that your table might be getting initialized before the new data call comes since the variable data is shared. Remember, even the put request takes a little bit of time.

Turning the process async using promises might fix your problem.

2. You are using the back button on chrome. If you don't force update on refresh, then there is a high chance that a cached version is being served to you and refreshing makes chrome fetch again.

You will have to share more code with us to get a more accurate answer. If I have completely missed the edit action being handled in the given code, please let me know where.